# Convert NodeList to Array for a Stepper to work with IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a simple Vanilla JS horizontal stepper without the addition of CSS or JS libraries.
I have found [this](https://codepen.io/jamesqquick/pen/KKwZgQb) example but it doesnt work with IE browser.
The problem is the following line:

```
const  bullets  =  [...document.querySelectorAll('.bullet')];
```

where he is converting the NodeList of 'divs' with class .bullet to Array.
Is there any way to make it work because I have tried "Array.prototype.slice" and copy the Nodelist in a JS array without success..

Comment: Can u please try this  -> const  bullets  =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.bullet'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just iterate though the the nodeList with something like a for loop and add the nodelist item to the array . Something like this:

```js
let bulletsArray = [];
let bullets = document.querySelectorAll('bullets');
for(let i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
    bulletsArray.push(bullets[i])
}
```

Heres a working demo: https://codepen.io/inklingboi/pen/BapmdBw?editors=1010
Note: my initial idea was to use Array.from() but after checking its compatibility list on mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from  i noticed that it isnt supported in IE

Answer (score 0):

It seems that IE does not support addEventListener() function because I get an error at that line:

```
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {..});
```